# Problem with CSS and IE8, Box has an overflowing/repeating image in IE8 only! Please help!

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with a few div boxes displaying an overflowing/repeating image only in Internet Explorer 8. It works fine in Chrome & Firefox.

**Link to an image of the Problem:**http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/2209/cssproblem.png

I'm really not sure what's going on.. Note. In the image above I have highlighted the CSS classes that match their divs. Here is some of the CSS & HTML code I'm using:

**HTML:** (Note: I have removed all the form elements inside the box because I removed it, and the problem still remained)

```
    <div class="introtext">
            <h1>Where to Search?</h1>
    </div><!--introtext -->

    <div class="qms_search_container">

        <div class="qms_search_header">
            <h2 class="qms_search">What to Search?</h2>
        </div><!--#end qms_search_header-->

        <div class="qms_search_box" align="left">


            <!--Form Stuff -->


        </div><!--#end qms_search_box-->

    </div><!--#end qms_search_container-->
</div><!--#end intro_banner-->
```

**CSS:**

```
    .introbanner { 
        background:url(../img/header_bg.gif) no-repeat bottom left #FFF; 
        width:700px; 
        height:230px; 
        padding:0 0 30px 0; 
        margin-bottom:10px; 
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .introtext {
        width:194px; 
        float:left; 
        color:#FFF; 
        border-right:2px solid #FFF;
        height:206px; background:url(../img/intro_bg_left.gif) no-repeat top left #222935; 
        padding:12px;
    }

   .qms_search_container {
         float:right;
         width:456px;
         height:206px;
         padding:12px;
         overflow:hidden;
         background:url('../public/frontend/img/area_banner.jpg') no-repeat top left #ffffff;

   }

   .qms_search_header {
         width:430px;
         height:32px;
    }


    .qms_search_header h2 {
         margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0; color:#FFF; font-weight:100; font-size:20px; background-image:none; height:auto;
    }


     .qms_search_box {
          width:436px;
          height:164px;
          background:url(../img/qms_search_bg.png);
          padding:5px;
          overflow:hidden;
     }
```

I've been stuck on this problem for so long now, Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Danny.

Comment: start with putting the background colour at the beginning of the line, and the background position horizontal first, and then vertical. Like: `background: #ffffff url('../public/frontend/img/area_banner.jpg') no-repeat left top;`. Have a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

Comment: Afraid it still shows up weird in IE8 :(

Comment: Is the container that is overflowing  .qms_search_container ?

Try setting the Z-Index to something different?  I had a problem with z-indexes in IE before, without seeing the full code, I can't test it.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll play round with it.. In the mean time I have uploaded the entire site to a test server. The same page on the screenshot is at: http://samvaughton.com/search. If you don't mind having a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you posted [samvaughton.com/search](http://%20samvaughton.com/search), you have invalid HTML around the problem area in IE. If you check in the IE developer tools, `<div class="introtext">` does not seem to be closed properly, so the right hand content is interpreted to be in the same `div`. Once you have fixed your invalid HTML, make sure that the `float:right` `qms_search_container` appears before the left hand side in the markup. This should resolve your <=IE8 issue I think.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the HTML. I ran over it and corrected some things & now it works! Cheers!